# Ignite TcpCommunicationSpi : Can slowClientQueueLimit be set to same value as messageQueueLimit as per docs?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I am not completely sure of the meaning or the interplay between slowClientQueueLimit and messageQueueLimit.

As per the documentation, they both should ideally be set to the same value, https://ignite.apache.org/releases/2.4.0/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/communication/tcp/TcpCommunicationSpi.html#setSlowClientQueueLimit-int-

However when i do set that i see this in the logs, is it a minor bug in the check or should i change this?

```
[WARN ] 2018-06-27 22:32:18.429 [main] org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi - Slow client queue limit is set to a value greater than message queue limit (slow client queue limit will have no effect) [msgQueueLimit=1024, slowClientQueueLimit=1024]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From code the warning is correct, but javadoc is not. `slowClientQueueLimit` has to be less than `msgQueueLimit`, because when message is being prepared to sending, first are checked back pressure limits, and only then `slowClientQueueLimit`. If these two numbers are equal, sender thread will be blocked by back pressure before it could go to slow client check. What means client would not be dropped.

Set `slowClientQueueLimit` to `msgQueueLimit - 1` or less, and I'll suggest community to fix the docs.

Comment: Great...thanks for the answer, yes we should fix this in the docs for sure...i suspected this exact thing that's why i wanted to clarify...thanks @Mitya